# Both my Ubuntu and Windows OS aren't booting

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, bootloader

I have installed Ubuntu, but when I installed it, it didn't give me the option to "run alongside windows".

I selected the "something else option" and it installed successfully.

After restarting, it is not booting, rather it doesn't giving me an option to choose the Os I want, it says:

```
there is no bootable disk insert and press any key
```

So, how can I correct it?

When I select the "check for defects" it's showing me that there is an error in one file.

I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu a second time but it's still showing the same problem.

Now the only OS I have access to is the "Try ubuntu" option if I use the pendrive with the bootable system.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? UEFI or BIOS install? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I'm going to speculate that this is a `UEFI` question primarily.  While not a solution, I do recommend https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI which I'm reading myself to avoid this type of scenario.